# Axios blocked by CORS policy with Django REST Framework: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be wildcard

Tags: python, django, axios, vuejs3

Using vuejs3 and axios, I'm trying to make a API call out to a django project deployed to AWS API Gateway, and getting a CORS error on the chrome side.  Not sure what setting I'm missing here...

[image]

The preflight OPTIONS response returned is ok, but chrome is upset that the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is "*".

I'm using django-rest-framework with `django-cors-headers`.

django.settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

# CORS
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False  # was initially True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = "*"

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://mydomain", "http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080"]

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

vuejs/axios side:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const url = `https://mydomin/my/endpoint/`;
response = axios.get(url);
```

I thought setting `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` to `False` and defining `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` values would resolve the issue, but the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is still showing as "*".

Am I missing a setting?

Here's the Options header result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS as list like this

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
"accept",
"accept-encoding",
"authorization",
"content-type",
"dnt",
"origin",
"user-agent",
"x-csrftoken",
"x-requested-with",
```

]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried, but it didn't have any effect on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` to this. I tried it and worked

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "content-disposition",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried, but it didn't have any effect on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other middleware is preventing the CORS middleware to set the header. The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) states:

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
> any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s
> CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
> before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
> responses.

So try to change the order of the middleware, like:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ... 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**One:**

Make sure your middleware is as below

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

**Two**

Your CORS settings in settings.py should be as follows, notice the whitelisting. That helps protect your API from any access but to have that working use the commented block

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = "*"
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
]
# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

**Three**

Vue JS get request can be as follows

```
async login() {
            const response = await axios.get('url');
            console.log(response)
        },
```

Hope that helps.